# Can I change the physical monitor dimensions in "Rearrange your displays" on windows

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, resolution

This is my setup at work:

[image]

The two monitors have a resolution of 1920 X 1080.
The Dell XPS 13 has a resolution of 3840 X 2160

Trying to set up multiple screens in Windows makes the setup weird, as if the laptop monitor is way larger than the desktop monitors. This is because it has a higher resolution at a higher PPI. This makes moving the mouse between the monitors very awkward.

**Is there a way to make Windows realize that despite the higher resolution of the laptop screen, it is in fact physically smaller in dimension?**

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you